# SSO Implementation using SAML 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Im a newbie to the SSO concept and SAML.My requirement is in detail below :

1. having a common login page. End user will be logged in using credentials;
2. once the user is logged in, he will be redirected to my application. From there, we will have links to other application.

Here, my application is working as Service Provider. 
My question is : as SP, how could I generate SAML 2.0 request to other applications from mine? 
How to check whether my application supports SAML 2.0?(its java based). 
To conclude, how to generate and send/receive digital signatures through SAML 2.0?

Can anyone please explain me the flow first then direct me to some link?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Right now, your question is a bit too broad for being answered. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application support SSO? If not, it probably doesn't support SAML.

You need a client side SAML stack. - examples [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

The commercial implementations in particular have lots of example code.

For Java, look at the Spring SAML extension.

Also, get as much information as you can re. the IDP because that will determine what SAML protocols and bindings you need to implement.